# Accessing Contacts and Calendar Database

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an application *with Flex Adobe Builder, AS3* that will add contacts in the user contacts and may retrieve some and add events and get from the user calendar.

Flex didn't provide and API to do such a thing yet. So, can I access the contacts database by it's URI and select and insert into it directly?

If possible, I'd like an example.

Answer (score 1):

> Flex didn't provide and API to do such a thing yet, so, can I access
>   the contacts data base by it's uri and select and insert into it
>   directly ?!!?

Since you tagged this question as Android, is it safe to assume you want to access the contacts on the Android device?

Access to the contact database is not currently exposed via Flex/AIR APIs; so there is no way to get access to that data.

There is [this workaround to extend AIR for Android](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/); but it is complicated and I have heard of people who could not get it to work.

Comment: yes, as a First step, assume I wana access it on android, I'll check this workaround, thx a lot

Comment: @TheBigBoss If this isn't added to the API in the next version of AIR; then you'll be able to write your own APIs using Native Extensions; although very little public informationi is available.